# How can I shutdown all PCs(Linux) with a python script via a Linux terminal (all with ssh enabled and same username and password)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shutdown

I would like to run a python script that shuts down all PCs on my network. They all are Linux machines with SSH enabled and the same username and password. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, is better to use a `bash` script for that, since you can input commands through the `ssh` command on the machines.

for exemple, a line in `bash` to execute the command for shutting down a PC through ssh will be:

```sh
ssh user1@server1 "sudo shutdown -h now"
```

If you still want to do it in Python, Try using the `subprocess` Module or the `os` Module to execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

First at all, it is much better to use public key authentication for this than store your password somewhere (https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/).

Then you simply have to call shutdown command through ssh.

```
import os
os.system("ssh user@host 'shutdown now'")
```

Obviously your user in your remote system must have privileges to shut down the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ansible/info) (written in Python, with Python modules), with which you can manage remote servers (almost all OS-es).

more: [ansible: reboot_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html)

Here are some examples of how the Ansible code looks like for multiple reboot scenarios (e.g. `test.yml`):

```yaml
- name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
  reboot:

- name: Reboot a slow machine that might have lots of updates to apply
  reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 3600

- name: Reboot a machine with shutdown command in unusual place
  reboot:
    search_paths:
     - '/lib/molly-guard'

- name: Reboot machine using a custom reboot command
  reboot:
    reboot_command: launchctl reboot userspace
    boot_time_command: uptime | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

Ansible needs to be installed only on your computer (desktop/laptop/server) that will control all other nodes. There is almost no restriction on the OS-es or distros that you can control (this includes Linux, UNIX, Windows etc). The `ssh` connection needs to be configured (the user and password). Your code will not have to hardcode the list of nodes, username or password, it will be only a configuration.

This setup will probably be the easiest to manage multiple nodes at scale, and can provide capability add additional node management functionality.

To run `ansible` from Python, Ansible provides the `ansible-runner` Python package (PyPI, GitHub), which can be used for this.

```
import ansible_runner
r = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='/tmp/demo', playbook='test.yml')
print("{}: {}".format(r.status, r.rc))
# successful: 0
for each_host_event in r.events:
    print(each_host_event['event'])
print("Final status:")
print(r.stats)
```

more docs: [ansible-runner: python_interface](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#usage-examples)